# Julia package Pkg not found

Tags: julia, pkg-file

I have downloaded Julia-1.1.0 (from [here](https://julialang.org/downloads/)), then I executed the binary file (julia-1.1.0/bin/julia) and in the prompt I type

```
using Pkg
```

Julia returns:

```
ERROR: ArgumentError: Package Pkg not found in current path:
- Run `import Pkg; Pkg.add("Pkg")` to install the Pkg package.
```

if I type Pkg.add("Pkg"), julia returns

```
ERROR: UndefVarError: Pkg not defined
```

How can I get Pkg to wotk?

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Have you tried Julia's new package system by typing [`]`](https://julialang.github.io/Pkg.jl/v1/getting-started/) at the prompt?  There's lots, probably most, of documentation that still refers to the old package system.

Comment: What is your OS? Have you installed a very old version of julia before? Could you try the solution here? https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/27359#issuecomment-395278485 Other reasons for the issue might be you do not have the necessary privileges to read/write to or to create the `.julia` directory.

Comment: You should be able to do `using Pkg` on 1.1. Try hckr's solution

Comment: I type " ] " in the prompt, and when it changed to "(v1.1) pkg>" I wrote "add IJulia", and julia returned "   Cloning registry from "https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git"
ERROR: failed to clone from https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git, error: GitError(Code:ECERTIFICATE, Class:SSL, the SSL certificate is invalid: 0x08 - The certificate is not correctly signed by the trusted CA)". Julia returns the same error with others packages.

Comment: Your problems seem to show that you are using Julia on some non-standard configuration of OS. Have you tried using the advice from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45489105/julia-certificate-error?

Answer (score 1):

In the comments to this question a SSL certificate error was mentioned. A solution on Linux (Ubuntu in my case) is to specify the location of the ssl certificates in the following manner;

```
julia> using LibGit2

julia> LibGit2.set_ssl_cert_locations("/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure this was not the OP's issue, but it is the reason I ended up at this question, so I will share this nevertheless.

I have a `deps/build.jl` script that used `Pkg`. This `deps` folder had its own `Project.toml`, so it could build the package without first activating the *package* environment (which would not yet work). It appears I had to add `Pkg` as an explicit dependency of that `deps/Project.toml` for this to work.